# Is there any way to create a PDF from a widget using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I did some research and find out that you can create PDF with images or texts or by exporting the screenshot, but I want to create much more like in the image below:
[image]

So what I want to achieve is to have a good resolution for PDF to print the PDF as a book after this. The physical book has a lot of pages and my client wants to create the virtual one.

So, I have the design (as you can see in the image), but I still need to create some text fields, signature and some logic in the widget.
How can I export after that to a one page PDF for every widget?
Screenshot won't be enough because I think it doesn't have a good quality and ofc the text and everything else won't be suited in the phone screen.

I am thinking to use the basic design and to add manually by code the texts, but I don't know how to export this to a PDF after that.

Answer (score 3):

Of Course!  The [pdf package](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) is a great start.

Comment: Its widget library follows the logic of the standard Flutter widgets, so it's pretty easy to recreate the same look with its widgets. Just don't put everything in a big widget before creating the book: the package requires "splittable" widgets in order to insert page breaks when needed. I usually create a Column with all my widgets as children, so the package can split them freely over the pages.

Comment: yep.  It's a little quirky, and be sure to use the printing package that the docs suggest.  Perhaps follow a youtube video to create something first.  Code with Andrea has a good one if I recall.

Comment: So can I create design also with this package and then export it to PDF? As an example the line with the diamonds, but not as an image? To understand what I mean, it should be Row(children:[Icon, Divider, Icon]); Maybe I will not have all images and I need to recreate design. Do you understand? also it will be a little bit hard to syncronize with the design backgrounds as you can see, need to approximate margins. Also, the user should be able to write text inside text fields.

Comment: yep.  if you can build it in flutter, you can output it as a pdf.  a little quirky, but straightforward.  when in doubt on something in error: add "pw."  You'll see....

Answer (score 0):

I had problem in Flutter to generate `pdf` from a widget

If anyone wants to

`generate pdf` , `image on pdf`, `custom font`, `download pdf` and `display pdf`.

I share my work here to help someone.

First install these 3 packages

```
  pdf: ^3.10.7
  path_provider: ^2.1.2
  open_file: ^3.3.2
```

You may add some below permissions

ios (info.plist)

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
```

android (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

You must import below in your Class

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
```

Below is my download function

```
  void _printScreen(statement) async {
   final Directory? directory;
    final ByteData fontData =
        await rootBundle.load('assets/fonts/Outfit/static/Outfit-Regular.ttf');
    final ttf = pw.Font.ttf(fontData.buffer.asByteData());
    final image = pw.MemoryImage(
      (await rootBundle.load('assets/images/logo_text.png'))
          .buffer
          .asUint8List(),
    );
    try {
      final doc = pw.Document();
      doc.addPage(pw.Page(
          pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
          build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.ListView(
              children: [
                pw.Container(
                  padding: pw.EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                  child: pw.Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      pw.Image(
                        image,
                        width: 120,
                        fit: pw.BoxFit.contain,
                      ),
                      pw.SizedBox(height: 50),
                      pw.Text(
                        "${widget.statement.name}",
                        style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf),
                      ),
                      pw.Text(
                        "${widget.statement.phone}",
                        style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf),
                      ),
                      pw.Text(
                        "${widget.statement.email}",
                        style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf),
                      ),
                      pw.SizedBox(height: 50),
                      pw.Row(
                        children: [
                          pw.Text(
                            "${widget.statement.month}",
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                                font: ttf,
                                fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          pw.SizedBox(width: 10),
                          pw.Text(
                            "${widget.statement.year}",
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                                font: ttf,
                                fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      pw.Text(
                        "Monthly statement",
                        style: pw.TextStyle(
                          font: ttf,
                          color: PdfColor.fromInt(Colors.grey.value),
                        ),
                      ),
                      pw.SizedBox(height: 30),
                      pw.Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          pw.Text(
                            "TOTAL EARNINGS",
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                                font: ttf,
                                color: PdfColor.fromInt(Colors.grey.value),
                                fontSize: 30,
                                fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          pw.Text(
                            "\$${widget.statement.totalEarning}",
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                                font: ttf,
                                fontSize: 30,
                                fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      pw.SizedBox(height: 50),
                      pw.Text(
                        "Earnings breakdown",
                        style: pw.TextStyle(
                          font: ttf,
                          fontSize: 22,
                          fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                          decoration: pw.TextDecoration.underline,
                        ),
                      ),
                      pw.SizedBox(height: 30),
                      pw.Row(
                        children: [
                          pw.SizedBox(
                              width: 120,
                              child: pw.Text(
                                "Moving cost",
                                style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf),
                              )),
                          pw.Text("\$${widget.statement.movingCost}"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      pw.Row(
                        children: [
                          pw.SizedBox(
                              width: 120,
                              child: pw.Text(
                                "Travel cost",
                                style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf),
                              )),
                          pw.Text("\$${widget.statement.travelCost}"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      pw.Row(
                        children: [
                          pw.SizedBox(
                              width: 120,
                              child: pw.Text(
                                "Service fee",
                                style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf),
                              )),
                          pw.Text("\$${widget.statement.serviceFee}"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      pw.Row(
                        children: [
                          pw.SizedBox(
                              width: 120,
                              child: pw.Text(
                                "GST",
                                style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf),
                              )),
                          pw.Text("\$${widget.statement.gst}"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      pw.Row(
                        children: [
                          pw.SizedBox(
                              width: 120,
                              child: pw.Text(
                                "Tips",
                                style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf),
                              )),
                          pw.Text("\$${widget.statement.tips}"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      pw.Row(
                        children: [
                          pw.SizedBox(
                              width: 120,
                              child: pw.Text(
                                "Refunds",
                                style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf),
                              )),
                          pw.Text("\$${widget.statement.refund}"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      pw.SizedBox(height: 50),
                      pw.Text(
                        "Total number of jobs completed for the month ${widget.statement.numberOfJobs}",
                        style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf),
                      ),
                      pw.SizedBox(height: 80),
                      pw.Text(
                        "THIS IS NOT AN OFFICIAL INVOICE OR TAX DOCUMENT",
                        style: pw.TextStyle(
                          font: ttf,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: PdfColor.fromInt(Colors.grey.value),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }));

if (Platform.isIOS) {
        directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      } else {
        directory = await getDownloadsDirectory();
      }

      if (directory == null) {
        CustomSnackbar.showBottom(context, "Document directory not available");
        return;
      }
      String path = directory.path;
      String myFile =
          '${path}/Tingsapp-statement-${statement.month}-${statement.year}.pdf';
      final file = File(myFile);
      await file.writeAsBytes(await doc.save());
      OpenFile.open(myFile);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("$e");
      CustomSnackbar.showBottom(context, "$e");
    }
  }
```

I hope this help someone.